# synchronize combobox html with textfield

Tags: php, combobox, synchronization, textfield

```
+---------+------------+
| class   | name       | 
+---------+------------+
| 10021   | John       | 
| 10027   | Alex       |  
| 10030   | Brian      |  
| 10033   | Anita      |
+---------+------------+
```

I'm trying to sync my `textfield` when I select one of the menus from the combobox :

```
<?
$cn=mysql_connect("localhost","root") or die("Note: " . mysql_error());
$res=mysql_select_db("psi",$cn) or die("Note: " . mysql_error());
$sql = "select name, class from list;";
$res=mysql_query($sql) or die("Note: " . mysql_error());
?>

<select name="names">

<?
while($ri = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
                //this comboBox works well
        echo "<option value=" .$ri['name'] . ">" . $ri['name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select> ";

echo "Class :";

        echo "<input disabled type='text' value=".$ri['class'].">". $ri['class'] . "</input>";
?>
```

For example, when I select `Alex` from the combobox, my `textfield` should show the field with value `10027`.

Comment: what do u mean by -  field with value ? you want both value and text of select Box / 10021   and John  to be settled in textbox?

Comment: you nearly know what I mean, when I select "Alex" from comboBox, the textfield directly show "10027" because that field are related like the table.

Comment: have u tried the below ans ?

Comment: My heart bleeds seeing mysql_* functions still being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `value=" .$ri['name'] to value=" .$ri['class']` which is in while loop,
and then use on change of select box 
to change the textbox value with JQuery ...

**1)JQuery**

```
$('#idofselectbox').change(function() {
        $('#idoftextbox').val($('#cardtype :selected').val());
          /*OR    $('#idoftextbox').val($(this).val());  */
});
```

Also

```
echo "<input disabled type='text' value=".$ri['class'].">". $ri['class'] . "</input>";
to
echo "<input disabled type='text' value='' >";
```

because we are setting the textbox value dynamically.

**2)Javascript :**

```
<select onChange="document.getElementById('textbox1').value=this.value">
    <option value=''>select a value</option>
    <option value='bhavin1'>bhavin1</option>
    <option value='bhavin2'>bhavin2</option>
        <option value='bhavin3'>bhavin3</option>
</select >

<input type='text' id='textbox1'>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/bhavinrana07/yjWmt/

Comment: what is cardtype? sorry I never try JQuery before

Comment: i have changed the code .. you have to give ID Property to select and textbox.

Comment: it works! thank you..
<select onChange="document.getElementById('combo').value=this.value" name="names">
<?
while($ri = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
  echo "<option value=" .$ri['class'] . ">" . $ri['name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select> ";
  echo "Class : <input disabled type='text' id='combo'>";
?>

Comment: I've another question, I just try another possibility...when I change the Alex's "class" field from "10027" to "ABCD EFG" then select it from comboBox, the textfield just show the first word ("ABCD"). how can it be?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<?
while($ri = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo "<option value=" .$ri['name'] . ">" . $ri['name'] . "</option>";
}
?>
```

Change to

```
<?
while($ri = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo "<option value=" .$ri['class'] . ">" . $ri['name'] . "</option>";
}
?>
```

If that what im understand what you want